# How to account for spatial autocorrelation in adonis without using strata?

Tags: nonparametric, autocorrelation, vegan

I am an undergrad student new to much of these stats. I am using NMDS ordination and Permanova testing to analyze variation in cover type (using count data) at different distance classes (0, 3, 10 m) from ponds at 21 sites. In each distance class at each site there are 4 quadrats (12 per site). I have two predictor variables: burn zone (within burn zone or not burned) and elevation (continuous, m).

I have been using adonis function in vegan to run Permanova tests. I can use strata=site as a blocking term for distance class, as all sites contain these treatments, but cannot for burn zone (lacking all predictor treatments at each site).

I am running my models separated by distance class, but need a way to account for the autocorrelation due to the four quadrats being at the same site. If my count data is equal to 81 points scored per quadrat, is the simplest way to do this to combine the 4 quadrats and treat it as one? (One quadrat of 324 points). Would this impact anything negatively? Is there another way?